# Is it possible to connect delegate and dataSource of CustomViews in interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Interface builder, If I right click on a tableView, I get option of delegate and dataSource outlets which at times we connect to the file's owner which is in most cases the View Controller which implements these protocol,

How can I get a similar option for my custom view which has a delegate and a datasource property ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to meet these conditions:

1. The view's `Custom Class` should be set to your custom view's class name in Interface Builder (via the Identity Inspector). If your delegate or dataSource object is also a custom view, also make sure that that view's Custom Class is set
2. The `@interface` for your custom class should decorate its delegate and dataSource properties with `IBOutlet`. For example, `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <SomeProtocol> delegate;`
3. If you declared protocol(s) for your delegate or dataSource, the target object that you want to use as the delegate or dataSource should be declared as implementing that protocol

Comment: I was missing the second condition!

Comment: Yeah, `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` are simply preprocessor macros that Interface Builder use to determine which vars/properties to allow wiring up for outlets or actions. They don't have any effect on the compiled code.

Comment: Then it should also be showing up other properties which are IBOutlets ?

Comment: Should be, if they are declared properly.

Comment: How would you type nr 2 in swift?

Answer (score 2):

Create your custom delegate,

```
@objc protocol CustomDelegate: class {
func itemSelected(_ success: Bool)
}
```

Create your custom class and property of your custom delegate (Make sure you add @IBOutlet during the property declaration),

```
class CustomView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var cDelegate: CustomDelegate!
//...
//...
//...
}
```

Now, Go to the Storyboard where you want to add this custom view, Take a UIView and change the class then right click on it, you will able to see the property ("cDelegate") you declared. See the picture for better understanding,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by following these steps.

1. create new subclass of UIview
2. in .h file set the tableview delegate and datasource property like

   UIViewController
3. then implement the delegate and datasource protocols in your .m file. like you normally do.
4. OK. now in your view controller drag a view into the interface builder or create an instance programmatically.
5. set class of  your view to the subclass you have created. (in interface builder right side );
6. then put a UITableView inside this view. and drag connections to its parent UIview and select datasource and delegates.
7. thats all done now your UIview sub class will act as a datasource and delegate for the tableview..