# Connect subclass's custom delegate for control in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard

I've got a custom control with a custom delegate:

```
@class MyButtonSubclass;
@protocol MyButtonSubclass Delegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)delegateMethod:(NSString *)param;

@end

@interface MyButtonSubclass : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, weak) id < MyButtonSubclass Delegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* param;

@end
```

And I've created a button in a Storyboard with the custom subclass:

[image]

Is there a way to get the custom delegate to appear in the list of connectable properties in the Storyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Huzzah! The answer was quite simply staring me in the face. The `delegate` (or `dataSource`) definitions need to include `IBOutlet`:

```
@class MyButtonSubclass;
@protocol MyButtonSubclass Delegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)delegateMethod:(NSString *)param;

@end

@interface MyButtonSubclass : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id < MyButtonSubclass Delegate> delegate;
//                              ^ This!       
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* param;

@end
```

Comment: Updated answer for swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033450/is-it-possible-to-connect-delegate-and-datasource-of-customviews-in-interface-bu/50583434#50583434